# Question on Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra

I used to think that solving linear systems using the Cramer's rule is easy. However I got confused.

Consider a simple equation system

$$\underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} 
a & b & 0 & 0 \\
c & d & 0 & e \\
0 & 0 & h & i \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\  \end{matrix}\right)}_{A}
\cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
x_1 \\ 
x_2 \\ 
x_3 \\ 
x_4 
\end{array}\right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
y_1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 
\end{array}\right)
$$

Solving this using Cramer, I get

$$x_2 = \frac{\det(A_{x_2})}{\det(A)}= \frac{y_1 c i }{b c i } = \frac{y_1 }{b }.$$

So far so good. However, based on the last line it is obvious that the equation system can be simplified by using $x_1 = x_3$ to:

$$\underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} 
b & a & 0 \\
d & c & e \\
0 & h & i \\
  \end{matrix}\right)}_{B}
\cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
x_2 \\ 
x_3 \\ 
x_4 
\end{array}\right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
y_1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 
\end{array}\right)
$$

When I solve this to $x_2$, i get suprisingly a different result:
$$
x_2 = \frac{\det(B_{x_2})}{\det(B)}= \frac{y_1 c i - y_1 h e}{b c i - a d i }  .$$

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you are applying the [Rule_of_Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to a matrix of order $4\times 4$. Such rule holds just for matrices $3\times 3$. The first evaluation of $x_2$ should be
$$x_2 = \frac{\det(A_{x_2})}{\det(A)}= \frac{-y_1 (ci-he) }{adi-bci+beh}.$$
As regards the second evaluation we have that
$$\underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} 
b & a & 0 \\
d & c & e \\
0 & h & i \\
  \end{matrix}\right)}_{B}
\cdot 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
x_2 \\ 
x_3 \\ 
x_4 
\end{array}\right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
y_1 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 
\end{array}\right)$$
implies
$$x_2 = \frac{\det(B_{x_2})}{\det(B)}= \frac{y_1 (ci-he) }{b c i - heb -ida} $$
which is equal to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on hint of @GEdgar I found out what was my mistake.

I tried to carry over the Rule of Sarrus for a 4x4 Matrix. This is not allowed. See (in German): https://www.virtual-maxim.de/determinante-berechnen-2x2-3x3-nxn/

Thanks for your hints.